Getting dark mode in local output using \time and darkmode
I would like to have my pdf outputs be automatically in darkmode if compiled at night according to my local time (I of course won't use it when I prepare this draft for publication). I see that I may be able to pull this off doing some math with datetime2, but even by going through the documentation and related questions on SE, I haven't got an idea how to do the modular arithmetics needed.

Update: as pointed out by @enkorvaks , datetime(2) invokes the \time register internally, which stores minutes passes since last midnight (of UTC, based on my observations). I should only need to do arithmetics with this to get the job done.
Therefore I've come up with some code based on wipet's answer, and posted it as an answer after being urged in the comments. I would also like to know how to improve this crude code I've scambled together.

Platform information: I am trying to avoid using shell escapes, so as to make this procedure friendly to my collaborators using Overleaf. datetime2 offers minute-level accuracy, which is enough for the purpose; as for the the timezone offset needed for the comparisons, I only want the code to allow me to manually set it. This may be the actual source of my inability to implement this, as I get confused with TeX conditional grammar.

Different approach: many pdf readers support dark mode. Produce the pdf as normal and just view it in dark mode.

You may be able to skip the datetime2, and just use \time or some variety of \now (as defined here: https://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2002-April/000064.html )

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm fully aware of such options and I use them all the time. I'm indeed interested in getting dark PDFs at compile time, and have thus posted this.

@enkorvaks thanks, this seems obviously the way to go. I'll try this approach

I’m voting to close this question because the problem seems to be solved by comments

@MS-SPO In lack of better solutions, wouldn't it seem better to instead to have me put my updated code into an answer and accept it?

As pointed out by @enkorvaks , datetime(2) invokes the \time register internally, which stores minutes passes since last midnight (for Overleaf it is set to be UTC). Therefore I've come up with this clumsy attempt (based on wipet's answer):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{darkmode}
\def\timezoneoffset{8} % UTC+8 for overleaf; set to zero for your local run
\newcount\sunrise
\newcount\sunset
\newcount\minute % minutes passed since local midnight
\minute=\timezoneoffset
\multiply\minute by60
\advance\minute by\time
\def\setsunrise#1#2#3{\sunrise=#1 \multiply\sunrise by60 \advance\sunrise by#2 }
\def\setsunset#1#2#3{\sunset=#1 \multiply\sunset by60 \advance\sunset by#2 }
\setsunrise{7}{30}{0}
\setsunset{18}{00}{0}
\disabledarkmode
\ifnum \minute<\sunrise
\enabledarkmode \fi
\ifnum \minute>\sunset
\enabledarkmode \fi
\begin{document}
Auto dark output file using \texttt{\textbackslash time} and the \texttt{\textbackslash darkmode} package
\end{document}

On overleaf, you may rather bypass the whole \timezoneoffset thing and setup your timezone properly using a latexmkrc file; that would make sure the behavior is the same as on your machine.

Thanks ... can you pleae add what's missing to compile?

My experimentation shows \time gives minutes since midnight local time, not midnight UTC. As I write this I get 1291 minutes, which is 21:31 EST. That is not the same as 02:31 UTC. The \timezoneoffset is not working for me.

@LaTeXereXeTaL It may be because I tested on Overleaf; one may choose to detect the environment with some additional code, but I'll keep this so as I originally did intend to use the code on overleaf (and therefore it's not minial to any extent).

@LaTeXereXeTaL I confirmd that using a latexmkrc file can override overleaf's UTC setting.

Thank you for solving this problem. It's a shame the question was closed.

@LaTeXereXeTaL I honestly don't understand the one guy who left a downvote and didn't even bother to leave a comment. I don't really see a way to detail the question more than it is right now; but as long as it isn't deleted I'm okay with the situation.

The question is quite clear. Randomness rules on SE sites.
